# How to compare two columns and create new dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

My table:

```
    A           B           C           D           E           F           G           H           I
0   0.292090    0.806958    0.255845    0.855154    0.590744    0.937458    0.192190    0.548974    0.703214
1   0.094978    NaN         NaN         NAN         0.350109    0.635469    0.025525    0.108062    0.510891
2   0.918005    0.568802    0.041519    NaN         NaN         0.882552    0.086663    0.908168    0.221058
3   0.882920    0.230281    0.172843    0.948232    0.560853    NaN         NaN         0.664388    0.393678
4   0.086579    0.819807    0.712273    0.769890    0.448730    0.853134    0.508932    0.630004    0.579961
```

Output:

```
A          B&C         D&E         F&G         H&I
0.292090   Present     Present     Present     Present
0.094978   Not There   Not There   Present     Present
0.918005   Present     Not There   Present     Present
0.882920   Present     Present     Not There   Present
0.086579   Present     Present     Present     Present
```

If both `B` and `C` is not there then show `not there` else `present`

If anyone `D` and `E` is not there then show `not there` else `present`

If anyone `F` and `G` is not equal to `0` `present` else `not there`

If `H` and `I` sum is greater than `2`, then show `not there` else `present`

I want to write if functions or lambda whatever is fast in pandas and I want to generate a new dataframe as I have given an output. But I am not able to understand how should I write these following statements in pandas.

```
if (B & C):
   df.at[0, 'B&C'] = 'Present'
elif
   df.at[0, 'B&C'] = 'Not there'

if (D | E):
   df.at[0, 'D&E'] = 'Present'
elif
   df.at[0, 'D&E'] = 'Not there'
```

So is there anyway in pandas with that I can complete my newset of dataframe.

Comment: Your logic seems a little obtuse, isn't the condition for cols `D` onwards exactly the same?

Comment: yeah some logic are same i just want to learn how to make these simple logic work, so that I can in future easily apply different things. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @EdChum, hey I have changed my logic a little bit as you said such that I will learn different things. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Alexander is it possible for you to help me here. Thanks

Comment: @Andy Hayden need some help in pandas. if possible for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isnull` to determine which entries are `NaN`:

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
          A         B         C         D         E
0 -0.600684 -0.112947 -0.081186 -0.012543  1.951430
1 -1.198891       NaN       NaN       NaN  1.196819
2 -0.342050  0.971968 -1.097107       NaN       NaN
3 -0.908169  0.095141 -1.029277  1.533454  0.171399

In [4]: df.B.isnull()
Out[4]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

Use the `&` and `|` operators to combine two boolean `Series`, and use the `where` function from numpy to select between two values based on a `Series` of booleans. It returns a numpy array, but you can assign it to a column of a `DataFrame`:

```
In [5]: df['B&C'] = np.where(df.B.isnull() & df.C.isnull(), 'Not There', 'Present')

In [6]: df['B&C']
Out[6]: 
0      Present
1    Not There
2      Present
3      Present
Name: B&C, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hey great and thanks for replying. Its working but just can you tell me how to pass these new columns like ['B&C'] in a new `DataFrame` because currently its adding this column to the same table.

Comment: Assign it to a variable (`bc = np.where(df.B.isnull() & df.C.isnull(), 'Not There', 'Present')`), and then construct a DataFrame: `pd.DataFrame({'B&C': bc})`. You can put all of the other columns you want in that dictionary as well.

Comment: I need your help please can you see it once. Somebody downvotedmy question related to pandas. [Here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33142919/how-to-compare-values-in-pandas-between-two-different-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to take two columns and need to check the corresponding entries having "NAN" or not. In Pandas, there is a one stop solution to all kind of indexing and selecting from a data frame.

> `http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html`

I have explained this using iloc but you can do it in many other ways. I have not run the below code, but I hope the logic will be clear.

```
 def tmp(col1,col2):
        df = data[[col1,col2]]
        for i in range(df.shape[0]):
            if(df.iloc[i,0] == np.nan or df.iloc[i,1] == np.nan):
                df.iloc[i,2]="Not Present"
            else:
                df.iloc[i,2]="Present"
```

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to understand, can yo just give me one set of examples. just one.if possible please.

Comment: You shouldn't use `==` to compare something to `nan`, because `nan == nan` is defined to be False.