# How to compare values in pandas between two different columns?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

My Table:

```
A           Country     Code1           Code2
626349      US          640AD1237       407223
702747      NaN         IO1062123       407255
824316      US          NaN             NaN
712947      US          00220221        870262123
278147      Canada      721AC31234      109123
278144      Canada      NaN             7214234321
278142      Canada      72142QW134      109123AS12
```

Here in the above table I need to check country and code.

I want a 5th column with correct or wrong, pseudocode:

```
If 'Country' == 'US' and (length(Code1) OR length(Code2) == 9):
    Add values to 5th column as correct.
else:
    Add values to 5th column as incorrect.

If 'Country' == 'Canada' and (length(Code1) OR length(Code2) == 10):
    Add values to 5th column as correct.
else:
    Add values to 5th column as incorrect.
```

if no values are there either in Country or Code Column than insufficient information.

I am not able to understand how should I do this in pandas. Please help. Thanks.

I tried to first find the length of rows of Code1 and Code2 and store it in different `df` but after that I am not able to Compare the different set of data as what I need to do.

```
Len1 = df.Code1.map(len)
Len2 = df.Code2.map(len)
LengthCode = pd.DataFrame({'Len_Code1': Len1,'Len_Code2': Len2})
```

Please tell me the better way of how to do this in single dataframe if possible.

**I tried this**

```
df[(df.Country == 'US') & ((df.Code1.str.len() == 9)|(df.Code2.str.len() == 9))|(df.Country == 'Canada') & ((df.Code1.str.len() == 10)|(df.Code2.str.len() == 10))]
```

But it is getting long and I will not be able to write for many countries.

Comment: Can you please tell me what was wrong or I you down voted my question

Comment: @Evan Wright can you please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you a 'is_correct' boolean column:

```
code_lengths = {'US':9, 'Canada':10}
df['correct_code_length'] = df.Country.replace(code_lengths)
df['is_correct'] = (df.Code1.apply(lambda x: len(str(x))) == df.correct_code_length) | (df.Code2.apply(lambda x: len(str(x))) == df.correct_code_length)
```

You will need to populate the code_lengths dictionary with more countries as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I ask 1 more solution if possible without the lambda. But a great help.

Comment: If you can set the type of the codes to strings when you read in the data, then you can replace the lambda function with 'len'. You might have problems if one of the country code lengths is 3 as NaNs will be interpreted as the correct length, so you will need to replace the NaNs.